# $k$-dependence of the energy in solid state physics

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, electronic-band-theory

In a crystal, the electrons are subject to a periodic potential due to the fact that the atoms form a periodic lattice. From this periodicity we can obtain the Bloch theorem, and get a general formula for the electron wave function, known as the Bloch function.

Through the Bloch theorem, it seems that we can show the existence of band structures, *i.e.* that the electronic energies depend on $k$ and on an integer $n$ referring to the band index, and do *not* depend on $x$. This means we have a Schrödinger equation of the form (in 1D):

$$\left[ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x) \right] \Psi_{nk}(x) = E_n(k) \Psi_{nk}(x),$$
with $V$ a periodic potential, and $\Psi_{nk}(x)$ a Bloch function.

My question is: how can we prove that this non-dependence of the energy on $x$ is true for *any* periodic potential $V$? I could find examples for specific $V$'s, like for rectangular potential barriers, but not in general.

Comment: This isn't unique to periodic potentials - think about the cases you solved in elementary quantum mechanics - the square well, the harmonic oscillator, the hydrogen atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about KF Gauss's answer, I realized the mistake I made when wondering why the energy did not depend on $x$, as indeed it should not, by simple definition of the energy in the Schrödinger equation. I am thus putting my own answer here, for those who upvoted the question and might find this helpful.

What got me confused was the fact that everything depends on $k$ in solid-state physics, and along the way I forgot that $k$ is not equivalent to $x$.

Let us take the Schrödinger equation in the Dirac notation:
$$ H |\Psi\rangle = E |\Psi\rangle. $$
If we project this equation onto the position basis, we get:
$$ \langle x| H |\Psi\rangle = E \langle x|\Psi\rangle = E \, \Psi(x),$$
*i.e.* the energy being a scalar, it does not depend on the basis considered, and in particular it does not depend on position.

In contrast, I don't think that the crystal momentum $k$ can form such a basis on which $|\Psi\rangle$ can be projected, making it possible for the energy to depend on $k$. Unfortunately my mathematical demonstration comes short on this point...

<sub>My intuition is that, unlike the momentum $p$ which corresponds to the momentum-space basis on which we *can* equivalently project $|\Psi\rangle$, $k$ is only conserved *modulo* a lattice vector, and is thus not proportional to $p$.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is confused, the quantum numbers $k$ and $n$ denote a wavefunction with a particular spatial dependence $\psi(x)$ and energy $E_{n,k}$. So in that sense, the energy *does* sensitively depend on $x$. One should note that this is the same result as that of the simple harmonic oscillator, which has states labeled by $n$, or the hydrogen atom with states labeled by $n,l,m$. In both of these cases, the quantum numbers uniquely denote an eigenstate with a particular dependence on $x$.

Perhaps what you are wondering is how to show that the energies of a lattice model are invariant upon translation by a lattice vector. This is shown in Bloch's theorem (see wikipedia link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem). One can see how this works by substituting $x$ by $x+a$ and recognizing $V(x+a)=V(x)$.